# How to limit Freebase results to those who have images

Tags: json, image, api, rest, freebase

I know Freebase is on its way out, but until Google Knowledge Graph is released, I need a way to search Freebase, but ony return results that have images.

I know I can check the 'property' node for '/common/topic/image' in the results set, but for correct pagination, I need to achieve this through the API call, not through server side code after.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Example call: https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search/?query=daughtry&output=((type)(created_by)(notable)(property))

Example response with image:

```
[result] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [mid] => /m/0f2jr1
                [id] => /en/daughtry
                [name] => Daughtry
                [notable] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Post-grunge Artist
                        [id] => /m/05jg58
                    )

                [lang] => en
                [score] => 44.129833
                [output] => Array
                    (
                        [property] => Array
                            (
                                [/common/topic/image] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [mid] => /m/03t3mnz
                                                [name] => Daughtry Live in NYC 12-5-07
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
    )
```

Without an image, the 'property' array is simply empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted a query which doesn't work at all (due to a typo), but what you need to do is use the `filter` parameter with a `has` operator.  The fact that the operator is not listed in the documentation makes it a little more difficult than normal to figure out. :-)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search/?query=daughtry&filter=(all has:/common/topic/image)
```

There's a little developer's app that you can use to experiment with the API here:

```
http://freebase-search.freebaseapps.com/?query=daughtry&filter=(all has:/common/topic/image)&output=(property)
```

Note also that `notable` gets included by default, so you don't need to ask for it and people don't have `created_by` properties, so you might want to qualify your search even further.

For example, if you just wanted albums with images, you could use something like:

```
http://freebase-search.freebaseapps.com/?query=daughtry&filter=(all type:/music/album has:/common/topic image)&output=(created_by property)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, this is exactly what i needed, and also more helpful than i could have hoped for. Its greatly appreciated

Comment: Happy to help.  Feel free to upvote as well as accept. :-)